# How to send icon as messages

Tags: android

I am developing a chat app and I'm trying to implement image buttons and when these buttons are clicked, the exact images will be sent as a message. It is like sending a custom emoji. These image buttons are called from the image resource from the drawable folder. So far the interface looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2uF3.png

The source codes involved are:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/contentRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow_top" />

    </FrameLayout>



    <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:padding="15dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



        <HorizontalScrollView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/bath"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/bite"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/bite1"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/blow"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/brush_hair"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/build"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/catch1"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/change_channel"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/wipe_face"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/drink"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/eat"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/go"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/go_in"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/go_out"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/knock_it_down"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/no"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon17"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/pull"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon18"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/push"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon19"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/roll"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon20"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/sit"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon21"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/sleep"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon22"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/stand"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon23"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/stand_up"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/icon24"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/throw1"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>



     <RelativeLayout
         android:background="#fff"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="2dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonEmoji"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/smiley"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextMessage"
            />
        <hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonMessage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonEmoji"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonEmoji"
            emojicon:emojiconSize="28sp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonMessage"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextMessage"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener, ClickListenerChatFirebase {

    private static final int IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int IMAGE_CAMERA_REQUEST = 2;
    private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 3;

    static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    static final String CHAT_REFERENCE = "chatmodel";

    //Firebase and GoogleApiClient
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    //CLass Model
    private UserModel userModel;

    //Views UI
    private RecyclerView rvListMessage;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private ImageView btSendMessage,btEmoji,ivImage;
    private ImageButton btPecs;
    private EmojiconEditText edMessage;
    private View contentRoot;
    private EmojIconActions emojIcon;

    //File
    private File filePathImageCamera;

    //Tabs
    //private Toolbar toolbar;
    //private TabLayout tabLayout;
    //private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        btPecs = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.icon);
        //ivImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_chat);





        if (!Util.verificaConexao(this)){
            Util.initToast(this,"You do not have an internet connection.");
            finish();
        }else{
            bindViews();
            verificaUsuarioLogado();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                    .build();
        }


    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(Util.URL_STORAGE_REFERENCE).child(Util.FOLDER_STORAGE_IMG);

        if (requestCode == IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                if (selectedImageUri != null){
                    sendFileFirebase(storageRef,selectedImageUri);
                }else{
                    //URI IS NULL
                }
            }
        }else if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAMERA_REQUEST){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                if (filePathImageCamera != null && filePathImageCamera.exists()){
                    StorageReference imageCameraRef = storageRef.child(filePathImageCamera.getName()+"_camera");
                    sendFileFirebase(imageCameraRef,filePathImageCamera);
                }else{
                    //IS NULL
                }
            }
        }else if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
                if (place!=null){
                    LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
                    MapModel mapModel = new MapModel(latLng.latitude+"",latLng.longitude+"");
                    ChatModel chatModel = new ChatModel(userModel,Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()+"",mapModel);
                    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CHAT_REFERENCE).push().setValue(chatModel);
                }else{
                    //PLACE IS NULL
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.sendPhoto:
                photoCameraIntent();
                break;
            case R.id.sendPhotoGallery:
                photoGalleryIntent();
                break;
            case R.id.sign_out:
                signOut();
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Util.initToast(this,"Google Play Services error.");
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonMessage:
                sendMessageFirebase();
            case R.id.icon:
                sendMessageFirebase();
                ivImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.bath);
                break;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void clickImageChat(View view, int position,String nameUser,String urlPhotoUser,String urlPhotoClick) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,FullScreenImageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("nameUser",nameUser);
        intent.putExtra("urlPhotoUser",urlPhotoUser);
        intent.putExtra("urlPhotoClick",urlPhotoClick);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void clickImageMapChat(View view, int position,String latitude,String longitude) {
        String uri = String.format("geo:%s,%s?z=17&q=%s,%s", latitude,longitude,latitude,longitude);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    /**
     * Envia o arvquivo para o firebase
     */
    private void sendFileFirebase(StorageReference storageReference, final Uri file){
        if (storageReference != null){
            final String name = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss", new Date()).toString();
            StorageReference imageGalleryRef = storageReference.child(name+"_gallery");
            UploadTask uploadTask = imageGalleryRef.putFile(file);
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"onFailure sendFileFirebase "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"onSuccess sendFileFirebase");
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    FileModel fileModel = new FileModel("img",downloadUrl.toString(),name,"");
                    ChatModel chatModel = new ChatModel(userModel,"",Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()+"",fileModel);
                    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CHAT_REFERENCE).push().setValue(chatModel);
                }
            });
        }else{
            //IS NULL
        }

    }

    /**
     * Envia o arvquivo para o firebase
     */
    private void sendFileFirebase(StorageReference storageReference, final File file){
        if (storageReference != null){
            UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(file));
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"onFailure sendFileFirebase "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"onSuccess sendFileFirebase");
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    FileModel fileModel = new FileModel("img",downloadUrl.toString(),file.getName(),file.length()+"");
                    ChatModel chatModel = new ChatModel(userModel,"",Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()+"",fileModel);
                    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CHAT_REFERENCE).push().setValue(chatModel);
                }
            });
        }else{
            //IS NULL
        }

    }

    /**
     * Obter local do usuario
     */
    private void locationPlacesIntent(){
        try {
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Enviar foto tirada pela camera
     */
    private void photoCameraIntent(){
        String nomeFoto = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss", new Date()).toString();
        filePathImageCamera = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), nomeFoto+"camera.jpg");
        Intent it = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        it.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(filePathImageCamera));
        startActivityForResult(it, IMAGE_CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }

    /**
     * Enviar foto pela galeria
     */
    private void photoGalleryIntent(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_picture_title)), IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }

    /**
     * Enviar msg de texto simples para chat
     */
    private void sendMessageFirebase(){
        ChatModel model = new ChatModel(userModel,edMessage.getText().toString(), Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()+"",null);
        mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CHAT_REFERENCE).push().setValue(model);
        edMessage.setText(null);
    }

    /**
     * Ler collections chatmodel Firebase
     */
    private void lerMessagensFirebase(){
        mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final ChatFirebaseAdapter firebaseAdapter = new ChatFirebaseAdapter(mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CHAT_REFERENCE),userModel.getName(),this);
        firebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                int friendlyMessageCount = firebaseAdapter.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosition = mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                                lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                    rvListMessage.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                }
            }
        });
        rvListMessage.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        rvListMessage.setAdapter(firebaseAdapter);
    }

    /**
     * Verificar se usuario está logado
     */
    private void verificaUsuarioLogado(){
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (mFirebaseUser == null){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        }else{
            userModel = new UserModel(mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName(), mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null ? mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString() : null, mFirebaseUser.getUid() );
            lerMessagensFirebase();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Vincular views com Java API
     */
    private void bindViews(){
        contentRoot = findViewById(R.id.contentRoot);
        edMessage = (EmojiconEditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
        btSendMessage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.buttonMessage);
        btSendMessage.setOnClickListener(this);
        btPecs = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.icon);
        btPecs.setOnClickListener(this);
        btEmoji = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.buttonEmoji);
        emojIcon = new EmojIconActions(this,contentRoot,edMessage,btEmoji);
        emojIcon.ShowEmojIcon();
        rvListMessage = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.messageRecyclerView);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    }

    /**
     * Sign Out no login
     */
    private void signOut(){
        mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

}
```

I have made the interface but I really really dont know how to make the buttons work.. PLEASE PLEASE I REALLY NEED HELP

EDIT: This is the ChatModel.java which handles the sending of messages

```
import example.asuspc.prospect.model.FileModel;
import example.asuspc.prospect.model.MapModel;

/**
 * Created by asus pc on 1/23/2017.
 */
public class ChatModel {

    private String id;
    private UserModel userModel;
    private String message;
    private String timeStamp;
    private FileModel file;
    private MapModel mapModel;

    public ChatModel() {
    }

    public ChatModel(UserModel userModel, String message, String timeStamp, FileModel file) {
        this.userModel = userModel;
        this.message = message;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.file = file;
    }

    public ChatModel(UserModel userModel, String timeStamp, MapModel mapModel) {
        this.userModel = userModel;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.mapModel = mapModel;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UserModel getUserModel() {
        return userModel;
    }

    public void setUserModel(UserModel userModel) {
        this.userModel = userModel;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public FileModel getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(FileModel file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public MapModel getMapModel() {
        return mapModel;
    }

    public void setMapModel(MapModel mapModel) {
        this.mapModel = mapModel;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ChatModel{" +
                "mapModel=" + mapModel +
                ", file=" + file +
                ", timeStamp='" + timeStamp + '\'' +
                ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                ", userModel=" + userModel +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: You could send the id of the image, and on the receiver end, handle that ID and show the image from resources instead of the text

Comment: @bogdanN thank you for the suggestion but can you please demostrate in source code? I coudn't get the picture

Comment: You can add some new fields for the image you want to send through the message into ChatModel, something like `iconPath = "/path/to/selected/image"` . When you receive the ChatModel on the other end, you check to see if iconPath != null, and if it is true, you can show the image from that path. This is one simple example. If you want to send multiple icons, you have to modify this.

Comment: @bogdanN I have edited the post and included the ChatModel. Would you mind taking a look and tell me which line should I include the required field? Honestly, I'm really new to Android and I have a lot to learn

Comment: So let me get this straight,I reread your question now to see exactly what you want to do. So when a user clicks the image, it is sent right then, not along with a text message, just the Image ?

Comment: @bogdanN yes just the image...it is suppose to send the exact image from what is displayed at the icon. It is similar to sending a sticker like in FB Messenger

Comment: I started to write an answer but realised that your UI is a mess. You have 22 imageviews inside an xml. What happens if you want a new one ? You go and add number 23 ? I advise you start reading a bit on RecyclerView and see how it can help in your situation. About the sending of icon it is really simple. You have images on both phones (sender and receiver), you just have to tell the receiver to show the exact image that the sender pressed. Think about how you can do that (hint: use the same sendMessageFirebase method).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for encoding image to text, send image as a String and decode this to image using Base64 too.